# Audio not working in ubuntu

Tags: sound, 22.04, pulseaudio, dell, alsa

I ma having some strange audio issues on my laptop(dell inspiron-3501, ubuntu 22.04 and kernel 6.2.0-39-generic ).
When i first turn on the laptop, the audio, microphone nothing works. But when i restart the laptop then it automatically works(but speaker sound has some cracking noises at first 2-3min only).
I sometime needs to restart laptop two times then only audio works. I am not able to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I personally had some drivers issue with the 6.2.0-39-generic kernel version and ubuntu 22.04.

Not with the same computer but you could try to go into "additional drivers" and try other or go back to the open source one if you're not using it and see if it resolves your issue.